# Inverse Laplace Transformation

Tags: laplace-transform

I was solving a problem but I am stuck at it. Here is the question :

$\frac{7s^2+9s+3}{(s^2-12s+40)(s^2+9)}$   Find inverse Laplace transform.

I performed these operation :

$\frac{As+B}{(s^2-12s+40)}$ +  $\frac{Cs+D}{(s^2+9)}$ =$\frac{7s^2+9s+3}{(s^2-12s+40)(s^2+9)}$

After calculations, I get 2 different values of B. one of them is $\frac{31}{4}$ other one is $\frac{33}{9}$ . Is there a problem about this question?

Comment: Try calling one of the Bs a D and the problem disappears :)

Comment: Your starting hypothesis should be: I've done something wrong with the algebra, not there is something wrong with the question.

Comment: @user_of_math I wrote B 2 times by mistake. Now I edited it but problem still there

Answer (score 0):

Multiplying, we get
$$(As+B)(s^2+9) + (Cs+D)(s^2-12s+40) = 7s^2 + 9s + 3.$$
Expanding and collecting terms, we obtain
\begin{align}
7s^2 + 9s+3  &= A s^3+9 A s+B s^2+9 B+C s^3-12 C s^2+40 C s+D s^2-12 D s+40 D \\
&= (A+C)s^3 + (B-12C+D)s^2 + (9A + 40C -12D)s + (9B + 40D).
\end{align}
This yields the linear system of equations
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & -12 & 1 \\
 9 & 0 & 40 & -12 \\
 0 & 9 & 0 & 40
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
A \\ B \\ C \\ D
\end{bmatrix}
= 
\begin{bmatrix}
0 \\ 7 \\ 9 \\ 3
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
It is easy to put this into row echelon form (multiply the first and second rows by $9$) and solve numerically from here.